# Show that the functional is sublinear

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Show that the functional is sublinear
$$
\begin{array}{rlll}
p:\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{C})&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\
\{t_{n}\}&\longmapsto&p\big(\{t_{n}\}\big):=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sup\textrm{Re}(t_{n})
\end{array}
$$
is sublinear, where
$$
\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{C})=\left\{\{t_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subsetneq\mathbb{C}:\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|t_{n}|<+\infty\right\}
$$

Show that there is a linear function $f:\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\{t_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{C})$
$$
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\inf\textrm{Re}(t_{n})\leq f\big(\{t_{n}\}\big)\leq\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sup\textrm{Re}(t_{n})
$$
Also, show that $f$ is necessarily bounded.

What I do not understand is, what Hahn Banach theorem's analytic-algebraic form should be applied, the real case or complex case?

What is it that I could consider, $W:=\{0\}$ together with the functional
$$
\begin{array}{rlll}
g:W&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\
\{t_{n}\}&\longmapsto&g\big(\{t{n}\}\big):=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}t_{n}
\end{array}
$$
but I do not know how to continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$
C = \{ (c_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^\infty: \lim_{n \to \infty} Re (c_n) \text{ exists }\}.
$$
One can show that $C$ is a subspace of $\ell^\infty$.
We define $\Lambda : C \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\Lambda(c) = \lim_{n\to \infty}  Re (c_n)$. 
As you can see $\Lambda$ satisfies all your requirements, but the domain of definition is not large enough. I think this is also what you were trying to do at the end of your post. To proceed you now need to extend $\Lambda$ to all of $\ell^\infty$.
Naturally, one wants to use the theorem of Hahn-Banach here. A suitable sub-linear functional on $\ell^\infty$ governing $\Lambda$ is certainly the functional $p$ that you defined at the beginning. 
Clearly for all $c, c' \in \ell^\infty$
$$
p(c + c') = \lim \sup Re(c_n + c_n') \leq \lim \sup (Re(c_n) + Re(c_n')) 
$$
and 
$$
\lim \sup (Re(c_n) + Re(c_n'))  \leq \lim \sup (Re(c_n) +  \lim \sup (Re(c_n') = p(c) + p(c'). 
$$
Moreover, by construction $p(\lambda c) = \lambda p(c)$ for all positive $\lambda$. Hence $p$ is sublinear.
Applying Hahn-Banach to $\Lambda$ and $p$ yields a functional $\widetilde{\Lambda}$ on $\ell^\infty$ such that 
$$
\widetilde{\Lambda}(c) \leq \lim_{n\to \infty} \sup Re(c_n)
$$
for all $c \in \ell^\infty$. Especially, this holds for $-c$ and by linearity this implies that
$$
-\widetilde{\Lambda}(c) = \widetilde{\Lambda}(-c)\leq \lim_{n\to \infty} \sup Re(-c_n) = -\lim_{n\to \infty} \inf Re(c_n) 
$$
we conclude that $\widetilde{\Lambda}(c) \geq \lim_{n\to \infty} \inf Re(c_n)$ for all $c \in \ell^\infty$.
Finally, it is clear by definition that 
$$
|\widetilde{\Lambda}(c)| \leq |\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup Re(c_n)| \leq \sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} |c_n| = \|c\|_{\ell^\infty},
$$
for all $c \in \ell^\infty$. This yields the boundedness.

I hope this helps. Please tell me if some steps need clarification.